# Probably a simple IIS rewrite rule question

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I don't know a lot about IIS and this is probably very simple. Even so, google and chatgpt are not helping me much. I need a 301 redirect.

I need
https://www.example.org/comm_dis/display-data.php?disease=30&month=3&year=2018

to redirect to
https://www.example.org/comm_dis/index.php?disease=30&month=3&year=2018

I have tried this with {R:0} and {R:1}

```
    <rule name="Redirect display-data.php to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^comm_dis/display-data\.php$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/comm_dis/index.php{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

this is the result
https://www.example.org/comm_dis/index.phpcomm_dis/display-data.php?disease=30&month=3&year=2018

I have other working redirects

Comment: So, what's the part you don't need in `action` tag? Remove that and you are good to go.

Comment: Don't know, that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Thanks for the h

```
<rule name="Redirect display-data.php to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^comm_dis/display-data\.php$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="comm_dis/index.php" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```